# How to display {% raw %} and {% endraw %} using markdown?

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

We know `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` could be used to escape other characters like double curly braces `{{`

But how to display `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` using markdown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the first `{%` inside a `raw` tag, so escaping it avoids the rest being processed:

```
 {% raw %}{%{% endraw %} raw %}
 {% raw %}{%{% endraw %} endraw %}
```

Or if you prefer you can escape both:

```
 {% raw %}{%{% endraw %} raw {% raw %}%}{% endraw %}
 {% raw %}{%{% endraw %} endraw {% raw %}%}{% endraw %}
```

Both alternatives produces `{% raw %} {% endraw %}`

Answer (score 2):

Use `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` just to escape the characters `{%` and `%}` so that Jekyll knows not to process these, and write the words `raw` and `endraw` as regular words...

Something like:

```
{% raw %}{%{% endraw %} raw {% raw %}%}{% endraw %}
{% raw %}{%{% endraw %} endraw {% raw %}%}{% endraw %}
```

Should output:

{% raw %} {% endraw %}